# What does laptop HDD "Specification supported SPC-4" means?

Tags: laptop, hard-drive

I just bought a new drive (from an online marketplace, so not official store).
Seagate barracuda 2.5" 1TB to use as laptop internal.

Comparing the difference with my current one, it has a difference of specifications.

I'm just looking at drive info from SeaTools (the diagnostic tool from seagate)
I don't know if this is needed but my OS is win 10 64bit

This is the new drive, connected via external USB
[image]

While this is the drive i'm currently using as internal (hitachi)
[image]

My question is:
I can't find on google what SPC-4 means, does it read that way just because i was connecting it via USB instead of sata?
Or is the new drive actually different?
This answer my Specification ATA8-ACS https://superuser.com/questions/819507/harddisk-standard-differences
But i can't find info on what's SPC-4.

I don't know much about hdd, so i'm a little confused because i have problems using the new drive as internal (cloned it, windows 10 booted but very slow.
While this installation of windows worked fine on my Hitachi/currently using drive)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Comparing the difference with my current one, it has a difference of specifications.

Well, one is connected internally, using [ATA8-ACS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA#ATA_standards_versions.2C_transfer_rates.2C_and_features), and one is connected via USB, using USB mass storage (which is basically SCSI), with the [SCSI Primary Command set version 4](https://www.t10.org/members/w_spc4.htm).

And that's because of the way they are connected; if you'd connect your new drive internally, you'd also see some ATA protocol.

> i have problems using the new drive as internal (cloned it, windows 10 booted but very slow).

That can have a wide variety of reasons, the most likely one is some Windows issue because of the way you did the cloning.

But connect the second one internally, and check the signal speed - if it's also 3 GB, then "difference in protocol" is not your problem.